# OpenCV in Cygwin - make: *** [Makefile:128: all] Error 2

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, cygwin

I'm trying to install OpenCV on my Windows, using cygwin, using these commands :

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
cd opencv
git checkout 2.4.5
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
make -j8
sudo make install
```

The Problem is after i try to use command: "make -j8" , i get this error at around 67% :

```
[ 67%] Building CXX object modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy.dir/src/calibfilter.cpp.o
/cygdrive/d/newbuild/opencv/modules/legacy/src/calibfilter.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool CvCalibFilter::SaveCameraParams(const char*)’:
/cygdrive/d/newbuild/opencv/modules/legacy/src/calibfilter.cpp:689:47: error: ‘CvStereoCamera {aka struct CvStereoCamera}’ has no member named ‘quad’
                 fprintf(f, "%15.10f ", stereo.quad[i][j].x );
                                               ^
/cygdrive/d/newbuild/opencv/modules/legacy/src/calibfilter.cpp:690:47: error: ‘CvStereoCamera {aka struct CvStereoCamera}’ has no member named ‘quad’
                 fprintf(f, "%15.10f ", stereo.quad[i][j].y );
                                               ^
/cygdrive/d/newbuild/opencv/modules/legacy/src/calibfilter.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool CvCalibFilter::LoadCameraParams(const char*)’:
/cygdrive/d/newbuild/opencv/modules/legacy/src/calibfilter.cpp:746:57: error: ‘CvStereoCamera {aka struct CvStereoCamera}’ has no member named ‘quad’
             int values_read = fscanf(f, "%f ", &(stereo.quad[i][j].x) );
                                                         ^
/cygdrive/d/newbuild/opencv/modules/legacy/src/calibfilter.cpp:748:53: error: ‘CvStereoCamera {aka struct CvStereoCamera}’ has no member named ‘quad’
             values_read = fscanf(f, "%f ", &(stereo.quad[i][j].y) );
                                                     ^
make[2]: *** [modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy.dir/build.make:639: modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy.dir/src/calibfilter.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4703: modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:128: all] Error 2
```

How do I solve this problem? I already tried using "make" instead of "make -j"
there is no difference

EDIT: I want to use the specific 2.4.5 version of OpenCV

Comment: Opencv 3.2.0 is available on cygwin, see https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/opencv/ . If you really need the last 3.4.5 you could at least see the cygwin source package for hints on building it.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I actually need OpenCV 2.4.5

Comment: but have you looked at 3.2.0 cygwin source packages for hint on configuration and compiling ? May be there is some setting useful in your case